# Exporting the data in pbf format, which is imported using osm2pgsql tool

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have imported the pbf data to postgres using osm2pgsql.

```
osm2pgsql -U postgres -W -d osmdbv4 --output-pgsql-schema=db_snapshot --latlong -H localhost -C 20480 --middle-schema=db_snapshot -S default.style  --prefix=aut --hstore-all --number-processes=24 --slim "country-latest.osm.pbf"
```

Now I want to create pbf file from this database. I see the option of osmosis, but the database schema of osm2psql and osmosis are different.

How I can export the data in pbf format, which is imported using osm2pgsql tool?

Comment: Same question was answered here already: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/discussions/1481

TLDR; There is no way to do this and it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: yes i posted  it there...so got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to convert pgsql to pbf for osm2pgsql generated data.

osm2pgsql is only one way process, currently there is no way for pgsql2osm

https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/discussions/1481